# Morse Code Application (JAVA Gui)

Tags: java, user-interface, morse-code

I am attempting to create a gui application that reads english user input and translates to morse (http://ascii-table.com/morse-code.php). I have touched on the basic parts of the program so far. My question is; what is the best way of going about reading morse? should i create a text file to import the morse letters off or should i declare each of them inside the program to translate? Next question is how would i go about doing this? please refer to a tutorial if possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you're asking how to create your Morse to English letter dictionary, then yes, using a file to read in at program start up is definitely a better way to go than hard-coding values in your program since this will allow you to easily update and change the dictionary as needed. If you're not asking this, then please clarify your question.

Comment: at the moment, my program is set to read keyboard input and print out the same in a label (i did this to test the code)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes thats exactly what i was asking. i also want to know if anyone could refer me to a good tutorial that they know of. Im doing my own research but cant seem to find a way to read letters from the text file.

Comment: Just look at the main Java tutorials on reading in text files as there's no magic to this, and any tutorial will help. I would separate the file reading code from the GUI code for several reasons, mainly so they can be debugged independently, but also in the future if you have further questions, you can leave irrelevant code and info (here the GUI which plays no part in your problem) out.

Comment: For something as simple as this, a basic text file or `.ini` type file would work fine, the latter where you use some separator, such as `=` between the two entries. For more complex data, consider XML w/ JAXB or a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Morse Code is not likely to change, hard-coding the mapping of characters to code strings is a valid option:

```
private static Map<Character,String> charToCode = new HashMap<Character,String>();
{
    charToCode.put('A', ".-");
    charToCode.put('B', "-...");
    ...
    charToCode.put('Z', "--..");
}
```

This map lets you convert messages to code one character at a time:

- Make a `StringBuilder` for the result
- Go through characters of the input one character at a time. You can use `charAt(i)` for that
- Convert the character to upper case
- Use `charToCode.get(upperChar)` to look up the code representation of the character
- Append the representation to the `StringBuilder`; append a space after it
- Once the loop is over, convert `StringBuilder` to `String`, and put it on the label.

Comment: `"Since Morse Code is not likely to change..."` -- but what if he later wants to add special characters, change languages, etc. Adding file reading is not costly in terms of time to write the code or length of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two files maintained outside. One having a mapping from Letters to Morse Code, and other from Morse Code to Letters. And then, you can build both the converters by doing a lookup from the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can Read the Input from the User and compare them while Run time to the Predefined characters and Numbers Stored in the Program 
Or you can Input a File and Read it using FileReader

But Here is the Logic that you are Supposed to Perform for Run Time Comparison

```
 char[] english = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
             'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
             'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
             ',', '.', '?' };   //Defining a Character Array of the English Letters numbers and Symbols so that we can compare and convert later 

     String[] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", 
                ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
                "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
                "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.",
                "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };

System.out.println("-->Enter the Sentence that you want to Transmit Using the Morse Code ");
        System.out.print("->");
        sentence = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("");
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase(); //Because morse code is defined only for the lower case letters and the numbers and the Symbols will remain the Same
        char[] morsec = sentence.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < morsec.length;i++)  //The loop will run till i is less than the number of characters in the Sentence because Every Character needs to Be Converted into the Respective Morse Code 
        {//For Every Letter in the User Input Sentence
            for(int j = 0;j<english.length;j++)   //For Every Character in the morsec array we will have to traverse the entire English Array and find the match so that it can be represented 
            {
                if(english[j] == morsec[i])  //If the Character Present in English array is equal to the character present in the Morsec array then Only Execute 
                {//Always remember that the condition in the Inner loop will be the first to be Equated in the If Statement because that will change until the characters match 
                    answer = answer + morse[j] + " ";  //After Every Letter is generated in the Morse Code we will give a Space 
                }  //Since the Letters in the English char and the symbols present in the morse array are at the Same Index 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-->The Morse Code Translation is:- ");
        System.out.Println(answer);
```